# Trouble seeing deinit in ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 VC's, LoadViewController and HomeViewController. This is inside my LoadViewController:

```
class LoadViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("init")
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated: false)
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

My HomeViewController has no code in it. I never have seen the print "deinit" and I am curious why the controller does not removes itself from the memory. I just want to show up a new viewcontroller, and remove the 'old' viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling present in a viewcontroller will not deinit the current view controller since the current view controller simply becomes the "presenting" view controller. To toggle view controllers, add something like this in your app delegate:

```
func presentHome() {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = nextViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func presentLoad() {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoadViewController") as! LoadViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = nextViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

From anywhere in you app you can call `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).presentHome()` to present your home view controller.

Comment: Thanks. After some google searches I found out I needed to change the rootViewController. I am doing this right now with UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nextViewController. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `LoadViewController` to modally display the `HomeViewController` on top of it. Both view controllers will be kept in memory as the `LoadViewController` is the presenting view controller of the `HomeViewController`.

In other words, you are adding the new view controller "on top of" the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

The `HomeViewController` won’t have its `deinit` called when you present another controller because it stays in memory in case you `dismiss` the other controller you presented and return to this view controller. If you want to know when its view disappears, though, you can implement [`viewDidDisappear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller/1397776-viewdiddisappear).